# Problems with Collection.sort

Tags: java, sorting

I keep getting the Bound Mismatch when using Collection.sort, I have no idea how to begin fixing this problem. The method that calls it is this:

```
    static LinkedList <Car> CarList = new LinkedList<Car>(); //Loaded LinkedList

public void DisplayAlphabetical() {
     Collections.sort(CarList);
} //End of Method DisplayAlphabetical
```

The LinkedList creates a car list to be sorted, using the parameters of Car from another class:

```
public class Car {
private String Model = "";
private String Colour = "";
private int Year = 0;
private int VIN = 0;
private double Price = 0;
static int TotalCars;

//Car Constructor
public Car (String Model, String Colour, int newYear, int newVIN, double newPrice){
    this.Model = Model;
    this.Colour = Colour;
    this.Year = newYear;
    this.VIN = newVIN;
    this.Price = newPrice;
    TotalCars++;
} //End of Constructor Car

//Get the car's model
public String getModel() {
    return Model;
} //End of Method getModel

//Get the car's colour
public String getColour() {
    return Colour;
} //End of Method getColour

//Get the year of the car
public int getYear() {
    return Year;
} //End of Method getYear

//Get the VIN of the car
public int getVIN() {//static Car C = new Car(Model, Colour, Year, VIN, Price);
    return VIN;
} //End of Method getVIN

//Get the price of the car
public double getPrice() {
    return Price;
} //End of Method getPrice
```

I understand that Collection.sort needs a comparable in it, but I haven't been able to figure out how to properly implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well how do you want two cars to be compared? Your method is called `DisplayAlphabetical`, so presumably you want to compare *some* aspect alphabetically, but it's not clear what. You may want to have multiple `Comparator<Car>` implementations instead. You should also work on following Java naming conventions.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention that. It has to display a whole list of cars followed by their model, colour, etc.
Alphabetically of course.

Comment: I know how to order Apples, Oranges, and Pears alphabetically.  How would you order Cars alphabetically?

Comment: By Model name, one of Strings in the constructor

Comment: @Sulphunet Good!  That's important to state, because cars are not **necessarily** ordered by their *model*.  For example, sometimes they are ordered by their price, or manufacturer.  So now you (and we) know, for your task, when you must compare one Car to another, you actually need to compare one Car's **model** to another Car's **model**.  You can retrieve a car's model using car.getModel().

Comment: @MikeClark Yeah, that's why I have the getter. Does that mean I would need to create some sort of sorting algorithm then? I thought that's what the Collection.sort was for.

Comment: @Sulphunet No, you do not have to write your own sorting algorithm.  You *do* have to tell Java's existing sorting algorithm how it ought to order things when it is sorting for you.  The way you tell Java how you want to order Cars is either through Comparator or Comparable.  Examples of both approaches have been posted as answers to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually prefer to use **[Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)** with [Collections.sort(List,Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) instead of implementing Comparable:

```
public class ComparatorTest {

    public static class Car {
        private String model;
        public Car(String model) {
            this.model = model;
        }
        public String getModel() {
            return model;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Car> list = new LinkedList<Car>();
        list.add(new Car("Golf"));
        list.add(new Car("Fiesta"));            
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Car>() {
            public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
                String car1Model = o1.getModel();
                String car2Model = o2.getModel();
                // TODO! return a value!
                // Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T) for more information about what to return
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Car implements Comparable {
    ...
    public int compareTo(Car c){
        // Implement how you think a car is compared to another
        //Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less    
        //than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
   }
}
```

Comment: Implementing a `Comparator` might be better, as carsdoes not seem to have a *natural ordering*...

Comment: Yes, I would also recommend not having `Car` implement `Comparable`, but rather using [Collections.sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)) and passing it a custom implementation of `Comparator`.

Comment: @Darkhogg fair enough, I completely forgot about COmparator.

Comment: No, there is no order. The cars are added in whatever order the user chooses and then sorted by the String Model

Answer (score 0):

**Sort With Single and Multiple Condition with Collectio.sort()**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;    
import java.util.Comparator;    
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;

public class SortingWithCollection {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Student> listStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();

    listStudent.add(new Student("Rahul", "01", 45, "2020-11-15T11:01:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Dharma", "08", 30, "2020-11-15T11:22:50.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Lalit", "10", 45, "2020-11-15T11:05:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Harshit", "02", 25,"2020-11-15T11:22:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Mohit", "05", 45, "2020-11-15T11:12:30.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Ram", "09", 30,"2020-11-15T11:22:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Lalu", "10", 25, "2020-11-15T11:28:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Sohan", "12", 30, "2020-11-15T11:22:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Neha", "04", 22, "2020-11-15T11:22:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Aaradhya", "01", 28,"2020-11-15T11:22:14.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Aakriti", "06", 35, "2020-11-15T11:22:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Sonali", "05", 35, "2020-11-15T11:35:01.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Billo", "08", 35, "2020-11-15T11:22:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Sohan", "05", 35, "2020-11-15T11:22:10.000Z"));
    listStudent.add(new Student("Rohan", "02", 30, "2020-11-15T11:58:12.000Z"));

    System.out.println("Before sorting List Is:");

    for (Student student : listStudent) {
        System.out.println(student);
    }

    Collections.sort(listStudent,new SortByAgeAndDate());

    // Collections.sort(listStudent,new SortByClass());

    System.out.println("After sorting List is:");

    for (Student student : listStudent) {
        System.out.println(student);
    }

}

public static class SortByClass implements Comparator<Student> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
        return student2.getClassName().compareTo(student1.getClassName());
    }
}

public static class SortByAgeAndDate implements Comparator<Student>{
    @Override
   public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
       if(student1.getAge()==student2.getAge()){
        return 
student2.getDateCreatedAt().compareTo(student1.getDateCreatedAt());
       }else{
           return Integer.compare(student2.getAge(),student1.getAge());
        }
   }
}

public static class Student {
 String name;
 String className;
 int age;
 String createdAt;
 Date dateCreatedAt;


public Student(String name, String className, int age, String createdAt) {
    this.name = name;
    this.className = className;
    this.age = age;
    this.createdAt=createdAt;
}

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getClassName(){
    return className;
}

public String getCreatedAt(){
    return createdAt;
}

public Date getDateCreatedAt(){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
        dateCreatedAt = dateFormat.parse(createdAt);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(""+e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return dateCreatedAt;
    }
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s\t%s\t%d\t%s", name, className, age,createdAt);
}
}

}
```